# Prime attribute when relation has only one attribute

Tags: database, attributes, key, candidate

My question is pretty straightforward. Let's suppose we have a relational schema with only one attribute, i.e.:

R (A), where A is the only attribute.

So {A} is the only candidate key.

In this case, is A also a prime attribute?

Thank you.